# How to use the bash timeout function for commands requiring sudo?

Tags: bash, timeout

In Bash this will set a time limit of 10 seconds for the *slowcommand*

```bsh
timeout 10 slowcommand
```

I'm wondering how I could get the same behavior, if I had to call *sudo* in order to run *slowcommand*, i.e.:

```bsh
timeout 10 sudo slowcommand
```

This will timelimit on *sudo*, not on the *slowcommand*... Is there an elegant way to do this while using sudo?

Edit: Let's assume *timeout* is not permitted to be run with sudo.

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo timeout 10 slowcommand`?

Comment: @Panki Reasons aside, let's just assume timeout is not allowed to be run as sudo.

Comment: Then include this information in the question - otherwise, that would be your solution.

Comment: You know what happens when you assume right?  Why can't timeout be run with sudo?

Comment: Essential read: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @jesse_b I would say having `timeout` in `sudoers` would be a pretty bad idea - just a guess

Comment: @Panki: if sudo is limited to specific commands on the machine than that is useful information.  A potential workaround would then be to create a wrapper tool that is allowed.

Comment: Exactly, as @Panki says, having `timeout` in `sudoers` would hurt more than help, other implications of sudo aside. Assuming might not be good in general, but I was really curious about how to get something like this to work with this restriction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`timeout` is not a builtin/function of the `bash` shell or of any shell for that matters (except if you want to consider busybox sh, where busybox commands can be seen as builtin of the shell).

`timeout` is a non-standard standalone utility of which there exists several often incompatible implementations (there also exist `timelimit` utilities with the same function).

In:

```
timeout 10 sudo slowcommand
```

Current versions of the GNU implementation of the `timeout` utility (from GNU coreutils, again distinct from the GNU shell, `bash`), run `sudo slowcommand` and sends the SIGTERM command to its own process group if `sudo` has not finished within 10 seconds.

However the process running `sudo` has changed user id, and the process that `sudo` has spawned to run `slowcommand` will also run with a different uid, so even though both processes will be in the same process group as that running `timeout`, `timeout` will not have the right to send signals to them.

There are possible ways around that. You can arrange for the kernel to send some signals instead of some unprivileged process like that running `timeout`. For instance, you could have it send:

- SIGPIPE if `slowcommand` writes to a closed pipe:

  ```
  sudo slowcommand | timeout 10 cat
  ```

  would cause SIGPIPE to be sent to `slowcommand` if it writes something to stdout after 10 seconds.

  (incidentally, here, `cat`, `sudo` and `slowcommand` will all run in the same process group, so that's the same as `timeout 10 sudo slowcommand | cat`).
- SIGXCPU if `slowcommand` uses more than its assigned limit of CPU time:

  ```
  (ulimit -t 10; exec sudo slowcommand)
  ```

  Would cause `slowcommand` to be killed if it uses 10 seconds of CPU time.
- SIGHUP if the terminal hangs up, and `sudo` is not session leader:

  ```
  timeout 10 script -qfc 'sudo slowcommand; exit' /dev/null
  ```

  (here assuming `util-linux` script)
- SIGINT/SIGQUIT. You could also use things like `expect`/`zpty`/`script`/`screen` to simulate a terminal and send a `^C` character after 10 seconds for SIGINT to be sent to the foreground process group of that terminal.